# R function stops after system() call

Tags: r, function, system, gdal

I've written a very easy wrapper around GDAL in R. It utilises a prewritten statement which is passed to system, creating an output, which I then want to read into the R environment again.

It works by creates a temporary directory in the working directory, printing out an ESRI shape file of our area of interest, and then cuts a raster by this, with some preset information.

My problem: after successfully running the system() call and creating the output file, the function stops. It doesn't execute the next call and read the output into the R environment.

```
gdalwarpwarp <- function(source_file, source_srs, newfilename, reread=TRUE, clean=TRUE, cutline){

  #Create tempfolder if it doesn't exist in the working directory.
  if (!dir.exists("./tempfolder")){
    dir.create("./tempfolder")
  }

  #Write temporary shape file
  terra::writeVector(cutline, filename = "./tempfolder/outline_AOI.shp" , filetype='ESRI Shapefile',overwrite=TRUE)

  #Warp!

  if(reread==FALSE){
    system(paste0("gdalwarp -cutline ./tempfolder/outline_AOI.shp -dstnodata -9999 -s_srs EPSG:3006 ",source_file, " ",paste0("./tempfolder/",newfilename)))
    message('warp warped TRUE')

  } else if(reread==TRUE){
    system(paste0("gdalwarp -cutline ./tempfolder/outline_AOI.shp -dstnodata -9999 -s_srs EPSG:3006  ",source_file, " ",paste0("./tempfolder/",newfilename)))
    newfilename <- terra::rast(paste0("./tempfolder/",newfilename))
  }

}
```

This doesn't run:

```
newfilename <- terra::rast(paste0("./tempfolder/",newfilename))
```

Comment: The `if(reread==TRUE)` part is not needed, you already have `else`.

Comment: How do you know the line isn't executed? An R function should always have a clear return value. Yours doesn't.

Comment: I can see that the output .tif file is created in the tempfolder, but it is not read into the R environment again. Could I choose e.g. return(newfilename) ? Or return(message("Done"))

Comment: Now I see it! Environment is scrapped without returning my output. Thanks! I'll remove the question to avoid confusing somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function did not return anything. Here is a somewhat improved version of your function. If you want to keep the output it would make more sense to provide a full path, rather then saving it to a temp folder. I also note that you are not using the argument `source_srs`

```
gdalwarpwarp <- function(source_file, source_srs, newfilename, reread=TRUE, clean=TRUE, cutline){

  #Write temporary shape file
  shpf <- file.path(tempdir(), "aoi.shp")
  terra::writeVector(cutline, filename = shpf, filetype='ESRI Shapefile',overwrite=TRUE)

   outf <- file.path(tempdir(), newfilename)
    system(paste0("gdalwarp -cutline shpf -dstnodata -9999 -s_srs EPSG:3006 ",source_file, " ", outf)
   
    if (reread) {
        terra::rast(outf)
    } else {
       message('warp warped TRUE')
       invisible(filename)
    }
}
```

I wonder why you don't use `terra::resample` or `terra::project`; perhaps preceded or followed by `mask` (I may not understand the benefit of using `cutline`.

Comment: This is very close to the end result. It makes more sense when you add the GDAL command `-crop_to_cutline`. This is probably possible to do in terra also? You are correct with source_srs, I didn't end up using it. I also removed clean.